# .NET OleDb parameterized query not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to pass this Update command to a database, it completes ok with no errors but it doesnt update the database and I can't understand why?

```
    Dim Cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim objCmd As New OleDbCommand

    Dim Con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & My.Settings.MasterPath)
    Dim Item = "08/08/2015"


            SQL = ("UPDATE [Hol Dates] SET [" & EmployeeList.Text & "]= @Htype WHERE [HDate]=@Hdate")

    Cmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
    objCmd = New OleDbCommand(SQL, Con)
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Hdate", item)
    objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Htype", "None")
    Con.Open()
    Dim ans = MsgBox("Do you want to unbook this holiday?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)

    If ans = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Con.Close()
    Con.Dispose()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing `Hdate` correctly ? I mean there is a possibility that Database date is in one format (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy) and you are passing different format value.

And I suggest you should fire a query using `Access` first in `Access Query Window`. That'll give you an idea

Comment: I've tried formatting the date to dd/mm/yyyy just to make sure, but it still doesnt update

Comment: I suggest you should fire a query using `Access` first in `Access Query Window`. That'll give you an idea

Comment: Could you try opening your connection before assigning into the command object?

Comment: Are 'item' and 'Item' actually different variables? Might be better to declare it as a datetime so that it is passed into the command as such. Your current declaration may be setting it as a string.

Comment: Item is the same variable, and I do delcare it as a DateTime earlier in the code. I've written the following now: `"UPDATE [Hol Dates] SET [Employee] = 'NHB' WHERE [HDate] = 10/08/2015"` and it still doesn't update even though the code executes OK. This is a basic Update command, I don't understand why it's not working

Comment: Method `ExecuteNonQuery()` return number of the affected rows. Check this number `If objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then ...`. If no rows affected it means that no rows exists in the database with condition `[HDate]=@Hdate`.

Comment: What type is column `[HDate]`?

Comment: Do you have somewhere on the top level `Try Catch` block which swallow   exceptions

Comment: @Fabio, I checked the `ExecuteNonQuery` and it isn't affecting any rows. `[Hdate]` is a `Date` type column. I've put a `Try Catch` in place and no exceptions are generated. Im sure I'm missing something tiny, probably to do with format of the date, I'll keep trying

Comment: Try create a parameter manually: `Dim param As New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@HDate", .OleDbType = OleDbType.Date, .Value = item}`. Where item is `Date` type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reverse the order in which you add the parameters to the OleDbCommand object. OleDb allows us to assign names to parameters but it *ignores* the names and only pays attention to the *order* in which the parameters appear in the CommandText.

Therefore, since your SQL statement refers to `Htype` and then `Hdate` you need to add the parameters in that same order.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didn't really notice the order I was doing it in. Learn something new every day!